# Cassandra use PHP SimpleCassie get all keys

Tags: php, cassandra

Is it possible to get all keys in a column family using SimpleCassie?
I looked at SimpleCassie's google code, but do not figure out.

Another issue is that I used following code to access column value.

$price = $cassie->keyspace('ToyStore')->cf('Toys')->key('Transformer')->column('Price')->get();

echo $price;

It always complains "object of cassandra columnorsupercolumn cannot be converted to string".
Is it possible to print out the column value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use get_range_slices, start with "", and after each call use the last key as the start key in the next call (disclaimer: haven't tested this with SimpleCassie )

How do you sort your columns within the column family? LongType for Price?

Valid 'compare_with' values are (from cassandra.yaml) : "AsciiType, UTF8Type, LexicalUUIDType, TimeUUIDType, LongType,
and IntegerType (a generic variable-length integer type)

Comment: I used UTF8Type to sort columns.

Comment: I figured out my second question. Use value() instead of using get(), it returns the column value. For my first question, SimpleCassie does not directly support get_range_slices(). It has range() to do similar work.